# Scrollbars appearing when scaling up content to viewport

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a width of 212px that I want to scale up to fill the device screen width. The content can be vertically centered (with margins).

So far I’m using:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=212,user-scalable=no">`

I’m viewing in Chrome device simulation (iPhone SE - 375×667), and this works, but the window has scrollbars. The scrollbars make it look like the page content is twice the size of the viewport, yet a scroll gesture moves the page vertically by only ~1px and none horizontally – they don't actually scroll the window. Testing on a real Android device as a web app, the scrollbars show initially (then fade out), and no further scrolling is possible.

This happens with an empty body so it’s not due to content, although I’ve tried limiting the body size with css:

`html,body { width: 100%; height: 100%;  overflow: hidden;  overscroll-behavior: none; }`

Why do these scrollbars appear? Is there a way of preventing them, or is there another way of scaling up content to the viewport size?

[image: screengrab]

Comment: Hello there Machine. What do you mean by "Scaling up content to viewport size" ? What are you trying to accomplish in general? What is it you want to do? Are you trying to implement responsiveness?

Comment: Have you removed the browsers default margin settings?

Comment: @somdow hello and yes, responsive in the sense the content (a puzzle game like a chessboard) has a fixed size which needs to be scaled to fit the screen width. There is no further change, e.g. on device rotation/orientation

Comment: @AHaworth thanks I did try `body {margin:0}` and that isn't the issue here